# C update timer without refreshing entire console

Tags: c, time

I have a simple program that:
a) generates a random letter  and prints it
b) runs a timer and prints it (needs to be updated)
c) checks if a random letter is pressed and if it is it stops the timer.

This is the code:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F2) & 0x8000)
        {
            char randLetter = 'A' + (rand() % 26);

            printf("Press:         %c", randLetter);
            statementX = 0;
            beggin = clock();

            while (statementX == 0) {
                end2 = clock();
                result2 = (float)(end2 - beggin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                printf("%.2f", result2);

                if (GetAsyncKeyState(randLetter)) {
                    end = clock();
                    result = (float)(end - beggin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                    printf("%f", result);
                    statementX = 1;
                }
                else {};
            }
        };
```

The output I want is for example:
Press X 5.26

But the actual output is:
Press X 0.01 0.02 0.03 ......

I will be thankful for any advice. `system(CLS)` is probably not the best idea because it refreshes the entire console, causing "Press X" to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the simplest ways to deal with this is to use the backspace `\b` character.

(For more advanced stuff, there are http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php.)

A minimalistic example (that updates the trailing number in place):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Press X:\t     0 "); fflush(stdout);
    unsigned i=1;
    for(;;i++){
        printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b%5u ", i); fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```